# Roblox Studio: MarketplaceService:PromptProductPurchase() player should be of type Player. How Do I fix it?

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

I keep getting this error on roblox studio: MarketplaceService:PromptProductPurchase() player should be of type Player. How do I fix it? Here is the code

```
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local LocalPlayer = Players.LocalPlayer

local productid = 1340456024

local function promptPurchase()
    MarketplaceService:PromptProductPurchase(LocalPlayer, productid)
end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(promptPurchase())
```

I tried changing the function deffinition, But it kept throwing the same error.

Comment: This is a LocalScript right?

Comment: No it isn't a LocalScript

Comment: I changed it to a LocalScript, but it immediately shows the buy prompt and it doesn't show the prompt when I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Your original error from the title was caused by the `LocalPlayer` variable being nil. That is because you were using a server-side Script, and not a LocalScript, which runs on the client. `Players.LocalPlayer` only exists in LocalScripts.

Other than that, the only other problem in your code is how you are passing the function into the connection. You have `()` at the end of `promptPurchase` which is calling the function, not passing the function reference. To fix your problem, simply remove the parentheses.

```lua
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(promptPurchase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using '''MarketplaceService:Prompt**Product**Purchase'''